# Style does not affect input in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying create a login page for my app. But style does not work as I wish, here is the photo from problem

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwKoC.png)

**Here is the login.html codes**

```
<ion-content class="app-content padding main-bg text-center">
  <div class="logo animated pulse infinite">
      <img src="../../assets/imgs/logo1.png" />
  </div>
  <form class="app-form">
      <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input sec-main-text">
              <input type="text" class="text-center" placeholder="username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input sec-main-text">
              <input type="password" class="text-center" placeholder="Password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-clear main-btn main-bg-color" ng-click="goto('/app/home')">Login</button>
      <a href="#/register" class="main-text-color">Register</a>
      <p class="forget" ng-click="forget_password()">Forget Password?</p>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

**Here is the login.scss codes**

```
 .app-form .list-inset {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: none;
  }

.app-form {
    .item-input {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      background: none;
      border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 30px;
      padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    .list-inset .item {
      border-radius: 30px;
      height: 46px;
      &.item-input input {
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
      }
    }
    input {
      &::-webkit-input-placeholder, &:-moz-placeholder {
        color: white;
        text-transform: capitalize;
      }
    }
  }


.app-form .item-select {
    select {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      background: none;
      text-align-last: center;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: -moz-center;
      text-align: -webkit-center;
      text-align-last: -moz-center;
      text-align-last: -webkit-center;
      direction: ltr;
    }
    &:after {
      top: 60%;
      right: 55px;
    }
  }
```

**And here is the what I want from original login.html :)**

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYsOU.png)

**And from original html's browser screenshot**

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJIoQ.png)

**And from my app's browser screenshot**

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alD74.png)

Thanks for your helping :)

**EDIT**

[After change html tags with ion tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Vqq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic introduces and uses their own tags,  for example, which has default styles added to it. It seems that you are using standard tags in your app such as  and . Change your input to something like

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

and things shall work smoother.

Ionic is fun to learn because it is easy. Have a visit the [Official Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#inset-labels) to see how you can make things easier. With the proper syntax, you will not less styling rules.

Comment: Great suggest, white textboxes has gone thank you :) But still I can't get action from margins and text center. Textboxes laying full width, and their texts begining from left. I need extra styling for this?

Comment: Read here https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/ . Ofcourse you may add custom styling when necessary. Can you post the a photo of the current output?